# I'm trying to animate a DIV within a JQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a JQuery slider the slides a main image with a DIV containing a title and short excerpt.
you can see it in action [here.](http://www.chazart.co.za/bulkmatech)

I want to animate (either a fade or blind effect from the bottom) the DIV that contains the title and short expert. I have managed to get the DIV to fade in on page load but then it disappears again once the slider starts. How can I get it to fade n on each slide?

This is the DIV's css

```
#postsnip {
position:absolute;
margin-top:-70px;
width:843px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#135086;
opacity:0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
line-height:14px;
font-size:11px;
color:#fff;
height:40px;
padding:15px;
display: none;
```

This is the JS

```
$slider = {
context: false,
tabs: false,
timeout: 7000,      // time before next slide appears (in ms)
slideSpeed: 3000,   // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms)
tabSpeed: 300,      // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms) when rotating through tabs
fx: 'scrollLeft',   // slide control: fade, scrollLeft, right etc.


init: function() {
    // set the context to help speed up selectors/improve performance
    this.context = $('#slider');

    // set tabs to current hard coded navigation items
    this.tabs = $('ul.slides-nav li', this.context);

    // remove hard coded navigation items from DOM 
    // because they aren't hooked up to jQuery cycle
    this.tabs.remove();


    // prepare slider and jQuery cycle tabs
    this.prepareSlideshow();
},

prepareSlideshow: function() {
    // initialise the jquery cycle plugin -
    // for information on the options set below go to: 
    // http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html
    $('div.slides > ul', $slider.context).cycle({
        fx: $slider.fx,
        timeout: $slider.timeout,
        speed: $slider.slideSpeed,
        fastOnEvent: $slider.tabSpeed,
        pager: $('ul.slides-nav', $slider.context),
        pagerAnchorBuilder: $slider.prepareTabs,
        before: $slider.activateTab,
        pauseOnPagerHover: true,
        pause: true
    });          
},
prepareTabs: function(i, slide) {
    // return markup from hardcoded tabs for use as jQuery cycle tabs
    // (attaches necessary jQuery cycle events to tabs)
    return $slider.tabs.eq(i);


},
activateTab: function(currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    // get the active tab
    var activeTab = $('a[href="#' + nextSlide.id + '"]', $slider.context);


    // if there is an active tab
    if(activeTab.length) {
        // remove active styling from all other tabs
        $slider.tabs.removeClass('on');
        // add active styling to active button
        activeTab.parent().addClass('on');
    }            
} }; $(function() {
// add a 'js' class to the body
$('body').addClass('js');    
// initialise the slider when the DOM is ready
$slider.init(); });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the 'after' call in cycle to add another function to animate those.

Comment: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/after.html

Comment: The name and versión of the jquery plugin?

Comment: Thanks Jason. I will look into that. Newbie to JS sorry.

Comment: Hi Robert. I'm using jquery 1.4.1 and the JS is a script from http://new2wp.com

Comment: @JasonLydon, I added this to my js script:
 function onAfter() {
    $('#postsnip').animate({
        top: "265px"
    }, 1000);
}
It animates how I would like it to but only on the first slide, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure i understand but i will try, put the div outside the slider and give it a minus margin top of its height, and put them inside a container,

```
#container>div 
{
    opacity: 0
}
```

and the code

```
$(/*Next Button*/).click(function () {
    $(/*this or the div*/).css('opacity','0').delay(/*Sliding time*/).animate({opacity:'1'})
 )}
```

Comment: Hi Roee thank you. I will try this but the DIV should animate with the slides and not on a click. Wish me luck :)

Comment: @roee, welcome to SO. Be careful about codes you submit as answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I managed to kinda get what I wanted and learned a few things about JS so thanks for that!